# Load file from WEB-INF folder using Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to load a config file present under the WEB-INF folder of the application using Spring.

I tried using the

```
private @Autowired ServletContext servletContext;
```

and then

```
servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/" + fileNm);
```

But the servletContext is being returned as null.

What am i doing wrong ?

My Methods look like this

```
public static SqlSessionFactory getSqlSessionFactory() {
  SqlSessionFactory  sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(myConnObj.getIpStream("mybatis-config.xml"));
}

private InputStream getIpStream(String fileNm){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try{
        inputStream = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/" + fileNm);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return inputStream;
}
```

Comment: Is the class containing the `ServletContext` object a Spring managed bean? Meaning, does it have an `@Component` (or `@Controller`, `@Service`, etc..) anontation?

Comment: Yes, I have added the `@Controller` annotation to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you try to implement [ServletContextAware](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/api/org/springframework/web/context/ServletContextAware.html) in your class that would make it override:

```
@Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext=servletContext;
    }
```

which will give you the servletContext?